# Solving $12(2\sin \alpha-\cos\alpha) \leq \pm 5$ for $\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

> Given
> $$12(2\sin(\alpha)-\cos(\alpha)) \leq \pm 5$$ how can I solve for the value of $\alpha$ in degrees?

I can't find any relevant trig identities, since if I square the equation $\cos(\alpha)$ becomes positive. Graphing $y = 12(2\sin(\alpha) - \cos(\alpha))$, $y = 5$, $y = -5$, and looking for the points of intersection doesn't seem to help, either.

I know the solution is $15.83^\circ \leq \alpha \leq 37.3^\circ$. I'm just unsure how to reach it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: The inequality looks strange. Is it a double inequality?

Comment: Hint: write the LHS as $A \sin(\alpha-\beta)$ for appropriately chosen $A$ and $\beta$. (note that you'll still need a calculator to complete the solution, it cannot be done analytically as far as I can see).

Answer (score 2):

A right triangle with legs $2$ and $1$ has hypotenuse $\sqrt{5}$.  Let the angle opposite the leg of length $1$ be $t$.  Then $\sin t = 1/\sqrt{5}$ and $\cos t = 2/\sqrt{5}$.

Factor $\sqrt{5}$ out of your left-hand side to get

$$12\sqrt{5}\left( \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\sin \alpha -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\cos \alpha\right)$$

$$=12\sqrt{5}\left( \cos t\sin \alpha -\sin t\cos \alpha\right)$$

$$=12\sqrt{5}\sin(\alpha - t)$$

where $t = \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{2}.$  Now it should be do-able.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If you use the tangent half-angle substitution $\alpha=2 \tan ^{-1}(t)$, the problem becomes
$$-(12+5k)+48 t+(12-5 k) t^2=0 \qquad \text{with} \qquad k=\pm 1$$ Solve each quadratic and select the proper roots to obtain the value of $\tan \left(\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)$.